# Single build of dist in angular for local,QA& prod. Read base_url from external property file

Tags: angular, typescript, build

I developed a web application using Angular 4 and Spring Boot.
Designed UI in Angular4. I want to build dist for Local, QA and Production.

Every time when I build I have to change the `base_url` in the file for local, QA and production separately. I have learned that I can use environment file for this purpose. But in that case also I have to specify which I need in dist buil command (e.g., `ng build --env=prod`).

In this case also 3 times I have to run this build command.

How can I avoid this by using a single command for build for building the dist at once for local, qa and production? 
Can I read this `base_url` from an external property file?

Comment: What about executing the  commands together?
ng build --configuration=local && ng build --configuration=qa && ng build --configuration=production
. You then set the correponding file replacements and the outputPath on each of the configurations

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any way to use an external property file in angular4 to read the base_url from outside the dist.

Comment: Not sure on a simple way to do that. But why not configuring it inside the environment files?

Comment: If configuring then also it required to join 3 build commands. right? I am trying to make 3 builds in one single command that's why.

Comment: Not sure how you will be able to do so, and also, seems a little risky to me. Chances are that something may be messed up between builds. Another alternative you may think of is using a task runner (maybe an integrated one on an IDE) to run all tasks you need at once.